# How do I let my image go off one side and on to the other side of the screen in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame (and coding) and can't figure out how to allow my image (xwing) to go off one side of the screen and onto the other side of the screen. I get an error with my current code that says. . .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Grant/Documents/xwingexample.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Grant/Documents/xwingexample.py", line 61, in main
    player_rect.x += change_x
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'
```

thanks!

**Here is the code**

```
import sys
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((1280, 800))
display_width = 1280
display_height= 800

black= (0,0,0)
white= (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
blue_violet = (138,43,226)

xwingImg = pg.image.load('X-Wing.bmp').convert()
tieImg= pg.image.load('tiefighter.png').convert()
space=pg.image.load('space.jpg').convert()

BG_image = pg.image.load('space.jpg').convert()


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    # Surfaces/images have a `get_rect` method which 
    # returns a rect with the dimensions of the image.
    player_rect = xwingImg.get_rect()
    player_rect.center = ( 800,400)
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0
    enemies = []
    spawn_counter = 30

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    change_x = 5
                if event.key == pg.K_a:
                    change_x = -5
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_d and change_x > 0:
                    change_x = 0
                if event.key == pg.K_a and change_x < 0:
                    change_x = 0


        # Spawn enemies if counter <= 0 then reset it.
        spawn_counter -= 1
        if spawn_counter <= 0:
            # Append an enemy rect. You can pass the position directly as an argument.
            enemies.append(tieImg.get_rect(topleft=(random.randrange(1280), -800 )))
            spawn_counter =  30


        # Update player_rect and enemies.
        player_rect.x += change_x
        player_rect.y += change_y
        for enemy_rect in enemies:
            enemy_rect.y += 5
            # Collision detection with pygame.Rect.colliderect.
            if player_rect.colliderect(enemy_rect):
                print('Collision!')

        # Draw everything.
        screen.blit(BG_image, (0,0))
        for enemy_rect in enemies:
            screen.blit(tieImg, enemy_rect)
        screen.blit(xwingImg, player_rect)

        if player_rect.x > display_width:
            player_rect = 0
        if player_rect.y < display_width:
            player_rect= display_width

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(40)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out line 75-78, you try to assign integer to `player_rect`, so after that, `player_rect.x += change_x` return this error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I suppose you want to change `player_rect.x` and `player_rect.y`, so you can try this, it works well.

```
if player_rect.x > display_width:
    player_rect.x = 0
if player_rect.y < display_width:
    player_rect.y= display_width
```